# Xcode 8 Extension disabled

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode8, xcode-extension

I tried to create new  `Xcode 8` `Source Editor Extension`, but for some reason basic examples are always `disabled`*(screenshot)* for me and I am not sure whether it is some bug with beta version or I am missing something.

So I created almost basic extension like from WWDC video and sample tutorials, and for some reason this menu item is always disabled.

I ran sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl in Terminal and reboot the Mac. I am using 10.11.5 Mac OS.

Also I tested working examples from github like [this](https://github.com/cyanzhong/xTextHandler) *(Screenshot 2)* or [this](https://github.com/BalestraPatrick/CleanClosureXcode) but they are also disabled.

**

*So my questions is*: Is that some sort of bug as Xcode 8 is still in beta or some configuration is missing from my side to make extension work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do the logs tell you?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I think it's just a bug.

This worked in my case: restart Xcode 8, build/run the container app target before, and then run the Xcode extension target.

Comment: I also experienced this. I had to found that this also happens when the extension hasn't loaded yet. Adding a log to extensionDidFinishLaunching helped see when it should be available.