# SwiftLint extension for Xcode 10

Tags: xcode, xcode10, swiftlint

I want add swiftLint for Xcode to extensions and according to [this install instructions](https://github.com/norio-nomura/SwiftLintForXcode?ref=ioscookies.com), first step I have to do is to go to terminal and write:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl
```

and I got:

> sudo: /usr/libexec/xpccachectl: command not found

So I can't install it to Xcode 10.

This repo is updated 8 months ago so it is for Xcode 9.1 and if it is really good idea to use it for Xcode 10?

What should I do to install SwiftLint extension for Xcode 10?

Comment: I think those install instructions referencing macOS 10.11 are really outdated. It looks like you might be able to get stuff to work but you'll have to piece it together yourself and ignore the `xpccachctl` stuff.
Maybe see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598768/xcode-8-extension-disabled

Comment: One issue with integrating SwiftLint at Xcode level is that it won't be available for other devs/machines/testers, etc. I would recommend to integrate SwiftLint with CocoaPods, like that it will automatically work for anyone using the code without any extra step.